# Using Matplotlib to create a partial multiplication table checkerboard?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My kid is trying to learn his multiplication tables and I was thinking of using matplotlib to create a partially filled out multiplication table for him to practice on. The tricky part is to have the text of the horizontal and vertical axes line up between the tic marks instead of being centered on the tic marks.

Any ideas about how to get started with this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about using a spreadsheet?

Comment: As @Thomas suggested, this is probably much easier to do just using your favorite software that supports tables like one of the Microsoft or Open Office packages (or equivalent).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As everyone has already said, matplotlib is really not the best tool for this... If you really want to do it programatically, generating HTML would honestly be easier.

That having been said, it makes a nice example.

The easiest way to tweak the axis label positions is to either replace them with text objects or just leave them as they are and turn on the minor grid.  (The label objects have a `set_position` method, but it doesn't actually change their position. I'm not sure if this is deliberate or a bug...)  I'm going to use the latter technique here...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

maxnum = 13
numfilled = 40
x = np.random.randint(0, maxnum, size=numfilled)
y = np.random.randint(0, maxnum, size=numfilled)
z = x * y

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for X,Y,Z in zip(x,y,z):
    ax.text(X+0.5,Y+0.5,str(Z), ha='center', va='center')

ax.axis([0, maxnum, 0, maxnum])

for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
    axis.set_ticks(np.arange(maxnum) + 0.5)
    axis.set_ticklabels(range(maxnum))

ax.grid(which='minor')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is excellent. Can you please give more info on what MultipleLocator is doing. I looked at the documentation on the matplotlib site, but it is unclear.

Comment: Effectively, it's just placing ticks every `n` units (with `n=1`, here).  The default tick locator for minor ticks places `n` ticks _between_ the major ticks.  Normally, you'd just do `ax.minorticks_on()`, but this would place 4 or 5 (I've forgotten which) ticks between every major tick. To get around this, you need to explicitly set the minor tick locator to something else. Because we wanted ticks at an even interval, `MultipleLocator` is the locator rule we want. Hopefully that makes some sense!

Comment: Incidentally, you could just skip with the minor tick grid altogether and draw the grid lines using `ax.axvline` and `ax.axhline`.  In retrospect, that's probably a lot easier to understand!

Comment: Perhaps ax.axhline would have been more direct, but I think the technique you have illustrated is valuable for everybody reading this.